# flash MenuBar component bug

Tags: flash, actionscript, menubar

When updating the data provider for a menu bar component, the state of the menu items fails to update until the user interacts with the menus (rolls the mouse over them, clicks them, etc).  For example, a disabled item remains enabled until the user roll the mouse over it. Is there a way to force a menu 'refresh' after modifying the data provider XML?

Comment: Is your data provider declared Bindable?

Comment: are you using a flex menu bar or an flash actionscript 2.0 MenuBar ?

Answer (score 1):

Just experienced exactly the same thing. For the problem to occur, you must've selected something on menu prior to updating `dataProvider`. this selection index lingers on internal member `oldIndex` and causes an error in menubar `mouseOverHandler`. I fixed it by clearing selection after changing `dataProvider`:

```
menu.dataProvider = newProvider;
appMenu.selectedIndex = -1;
```

Good luck.